# Yeoman Bower including jQuery twice?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, bower

I'm using Yeoman for a simple site. When I look at the Resources pane in Chrome, I see jQuery is being included twice (which breaks some needed Bootstrap js)

Bower list outputs this:

```
├─┬ bootstrap#3.0.0
│ └── jquery#1.10.2 (2.0.3 available)
├── jquery#1.10.2 (latest is 2.0.3)
├── modernizr#2.6.2
├── requirejs#2.1.8
└─┬ sass-bootstrap#3.0.0
  └── jquery#1.10.2
```

I've tried bower uninstall on bootstrap, sass-bootstrap, jquery, doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

This is completely correct. Both `bootstrap` and `sass-bootstrap` depend on jQuery. Bower has a flat hierarchy, so there is no duplication and since both require `jquery#~1.10`, there isn't even a version conflict.

That said, including both `bootstrap` and `sass-bootstrap` doesn't make much sense, because the latter is just the SASS'ified version of the former and thus works as a complete replacement.

Comment: Right, I see that the second-level on Bower list doesn't mean jQuery is installed twice. My issue is that in Chrome Dev Tools Resources pane, jQuery is listed twice. I think I just need to read up on Bower and RequireJS since it's not super obvious what they're doing and how. I take you're point about sass-bootstrap + bootstrap tho Thanks

Comment: Edit- *Your (not _you're_, sheesh..)